# Clients.openWindow() equivalent for same tab

Tags: javascript

So when I get a browser notification, I have 2 choices. If the client does not have the website up, I open a new tab. But how do I send the client to somewhere already on the site?

Basically, I want to have something like `client.focus("some/highlevel/url")` instead of `clients.openWindow("https://someurl.com")`

Comment: Are you trying to set focus to a specific tab programmatically?

Comment: Hi @guest271314 thanks for the fast response. Not exactly. I want to set focus to a specific tab AND inside that tab to a specific location. So as an exampe. If I have a tab up with "https://someurl.com" I want to focus on that tab and redirect to "https://someurl.com/someother/place".

Comment: Have you tried redirecting to a fragment identifier?

Comment: I tried window.open("url", "_self") but got: 'ReferenceError: window is not defined'.

Comment: You are trying to redirect a client from `ServiceWorker` code, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: You can use `postMessage` to post the URL to client `window` then use `window.location.href = "http://site.ext/full/path/to/document#fragmetnIdentifier"` or `const w = window.open("http://site.ext/full/path/to/document#fragmetnIdentifier", "_self")` at client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code to achieve the desired behavior:

```
// Attempt to extract notification URL
var url = event.notification.data.url;

// Check if it exists
if (url) {
    // Parse target URL
    var targetUrl = new URL(url);

    // Attempt to fetch open tabs
    event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({ type: 'window' }).then(function (clientList) {
        // No match by default
        var matchFound = false;

        // Traverse clients list
        for (var client of clientList) {
            // Parse url
            var clientUrl = new URL(client.url);

            // Check host matches
            if (clientUrl.host === targetUrl.host && 'focus' in client) {
                // Update URL
                client.navigate(url);

                // Focus existing window
                client.focus();

                // Avoid opening a new window
                noMatch = true;
            }
        }

        // If no open tabs, or none match the host, open a new window
        if (!matchFound) {
            event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(url));
        }
    }));
```

Comment: No matter what I try, it still opens a new window.  If I try console.log in the for loop I can't find the output to try and see why the clientUrl and targetUrl aren't matching.

Comment: @dev-jeff Please make sure that you are sending a JSON notification payload object with a "url" param ({"url": "https://example.com"}), and that the hostname of the URL you are sending precisely matches your website hostname which is currently open in another tab.

Comment: Try using the correct boolean name `matchFound = true;` to avoid the openWindow call.